# Can I change the font of the dataframes in R?

Tags: r, fonts, xlsx

I'm writing a script that creates an excel output. I want the fonts of the dataframes and all the other output be Calibri Light with size 14. On the internet I only find how to change the font in plots and visualisations, but I want it for dataframes and text.

I have found this example, but it's not working. Is it possible that I change the font in R itself? Or how can I make it work that it writes in a specific fontsize in excel?

```
calibri_light_14_style <- createStyle(fontName = "Calibri Light", fontSize = 14, textDecoration = "bold")
xl_write("Hello, world!", wb, sh, row = 1, col = 1, style = calibri_light_14_style)
```

**FOUND THE SOLUTION!**

For me this works:

```
calibri_light_14_style <- createStyle(fontName = "Calibri Light", fontSize = 14, textDecoration = "italic")

addStyle(wb, 1, style = calibri_light_14_style, rows = 2:6, cols = 1, gridExpand = TRUE)
```

Thanks to the link: ycphs.github.io/openxlsx/articles/Formatting.html

Comment: One reason why changing the font style does not work might be that according to the docs  `expss::xl_write` has no `style` argument.

Comment: @stefan I see indeed. Do you know a way to change it in R itself then?

Comment: You have to check out the docs, e.g. `expss::xl_write` has several options to style parts of the exported tables. Also you could check the docs of the `openxlsx` package which is used by `expss::xl_write` under the hood, e.g. openxlsx has options to globally set some styles perhaps including the font. See e.g. https://ycphs.github.io/openxlsx/articles/Formatting.html

Comment: @stefan I found the solution! Thank you so much!